# Does RestTemplate.exchange respect validation annotations of the resonseType class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

In code, i call make a request via RestTemplate.exchange like this

```
ResponseEntity<LocationDataCarrierDTO> response = myRestTemplate.exchange(
            uri,
            HttpMethod.GET,
            request,
            LocationDataCarrierDTO.class);
```

And the DTO class looks like this

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class LocationDataCarrierDTO {

    @NotNull
    private GpsDTO gpsData;
}
```

Is the @NotNull-Validation annotation taken into account by exchange? Aka: does the call to exchange throw an exception if gpsData is NULL?

Comment: no, validation annotation will not be taken into account. you can however integrate the validation with RestTemplate, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333587/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-java-bean-validation-api-with-spring-resttemplate

Answer (score 0):

`@Validated` to your service class, `@Valid` for the method you are calling, then validation will work